# how to block/allow access to a workstation(windows) programmatically

Tags: c++, windows, qt, block

I'm looking for a good way to restrict access to a workstation programmatically (like CyberCafé pro does it, if you know).
Here is what i did (but it is not so good): there is a list of processes of usual softwares stored in a file, and a little program that runs every 10seconds(when access is denied), this program reads the file and then kills every running process that is in the list.

The problem is that, in this way, the program will not block new softwares because it is not in the list. and you just have to change the name of executable so that the program will not recognize it, and will let it run.

So could you please help with a good way of performing this, all i want is to make the computer totally unusable by the user, and make it usable again but i want to do this programmatically.

this is only for windows OS; i'm programming C++ with Qt, but i can deal with any other solution if it solves my problem.

Comment: You might want to post this on ServerFault for an elegant way to do this from an IT Pro.

Comment: To the closer: this *is* an on-topic programming question. Come on, the word "programmatically" figures even in the title :)

Comment: @KubaOber Throwing the term "programmatically" into any random question does not automatically make it about programming. The above question is probably best solves with some sort of access control framework or policy enforcement utility, not by writing a program - unless the OP really wants to re-invent one of those wheels, which will not be a trivial task...

Comment: Maybe you're right when you say that it's not a good place to post my question, but i think you didn't get me very well. All i want is a way to do this, either by a framework or another solution, even if it's not really something to block/allow access but makes the user beleive that, i'll take it. So if you have any way, or any framework, or any idea, that can be helpfull for me please just mention it, and i'll look for it. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution may be to open a frameless, on-top widget full screen, and grab both keyboard and the mouse (using `QWidget::grabKeyboard` and `QWidget::grabMouse`). When you detect that your widget has lost focus (due to pressing Ctrl-Alt-Del and launching task manager), you can keep calling `qApp->setActiveWindow(this)` on a 100ms timer, until you regain the focus.

It's defeatable, but anything better will require platform specific code.